# Why doesn't tar recognize .iso files, even though the documentation says it should?

Tags: macos, command-line, iso, tar

`man tar` says that OS X's `tar` implementation should be able to extract .iso files.

> tar creates and manipulates streaming archive files.  This implementation can extract from tar, pax, cpio, zip, jar, ar, and **ISO
>   9660** cdrom images and can create tar, pax, cpio, ar, and shar archives.

However, `tar` gives me the following error:

```
$ tar -xvf test.iso
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

What's with the discrepancy?

The .iso is created from a .dmg using Apple's `hdiutil` utility.  `poweriso` can extract it without issue.

I'm on OS X 10.7.4.  `tar --version` reports `bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3`.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that it is not a pure ISO image so `tar` may not recognize it. I have tested `tar` on some random ISO images and it could handle them all, so it's likely specific to that particular image. Note that `hdiutil` can create non-ISO CDR images so you would have to explicitly tell it to use the ISO format (note that the ISO format is somewhat restrictive, so many CDs use a different format either in addition to ISO or instead of it).

Comment: I used `hdiutil convert -format UDTO -o foo foo.dmg`.  I don't see any way to be more specific with the desired output format.  I will try to find some more .iso files to test.

Comment: I tested it with a couple more files, and it silently failed for them.  There were no error messages, but it didn't extract anything.  Are you sure you're using the same version of `tar` and OS X as I?